# Does Google Chrome have different rules for cross-domain cookies in ajax requests in Incognito mode? If so, how do I find those rules?

Tags: ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I have multiple subdomains in my app. There is a parent domain cookie for user logins/session, and a subdomain cookie for cross site request forgery protection (CSRF). Requests go between subdomains using cross origin resource sharing (CORS), using the login/session cookie for all subdomains.

- main.foo.com is where the user logs in. The login/session cookie uses the domain `foo.com`.
- app.foo.com is where a large portion of the app resides. This is the active page when my error occurs.
- message.foo.com is used for sending messages between users. It is its own django app, with a csrf cookie using domain `message.foo.com` for use with its forms. It also uses the login/session cookie from `foo.com`.

So the user is on `app.foo.com/index.php` and an ajax POST needs to go to `message.foo.com`. The browser has made ajax GET requests to `message.foo.com`, which have set the CSRF cookie. The ajax POST is sent with proper CORS headers.

If I disable CSRF in the Django view using `@csrf_exempt` decorator, then the missing cookie is ignored and the POST is processed fine. Otherwise, I get the 403 error for CSRF.

The CSRF cookie is sent from Firefox and Chrome in normal mode. When Chrome is Incognito, the CSRF cookie is not sent.

From what I can tell, the difference between the cookies is their domain. The login/session cookie is set to `foo.com`, so all subdomains use it. The CSRF cookie is set by `message.foo.com` so it should only be sent back to that domain. But even when the request is going to `message.foo.com`, Chrome Incognito does not send the cookie. It may not have even accepted the cookie. (It's hard to tell if it didn't accept the cookie or if it's just not sending it back.)

This cookie scenario seems legit. The cookie is being sent back to the subdomain which set it. No other subdomains are trying to read or modify the cookie. The origin sending the request has been authorized with CORS headers.

Why does Chrome not send that cookie? Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Stack Overflow. This question isn't actually about what I thought it was.

The problem is that I did something in my Django code which was stopping the CSRF cookie from being sent to the browser. The non-incognito browsers still had the cookie saved, but the incognito one dropped the cookie when it was closed. So when I re-opened the browsers, they still had their old CSRF cookie except the incognito browser.

I discovered this when I renamed the CSRF cookie and all the browsers stopped working. I had seen the cookie in Firebug and the Chrome dev tools, so I thought it was still being sent when it wasn't.

So, the end result is that the cookies work as I expected. All my confusion was due to the cached cookies still being sent. As far as I can tell now, the only difference with Incognito is that it clears out all the cookies when you close the last Incognito window.

Hopefully others will be reminded by this question that the cache could be getting in the way of your debugging. Checking for that early in this process could have saved me a lot of time.